# Italicize title in tufte-latex

Tags: tufte

I am trying to italicize one section in my title in the [tufte-latex](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/) class. `\textit` does not work. `\itshape` and then `\upshape` works:

```
Non Italic \itshape Italicized Part \upshape Non Italic
```

But this is causing "Italicized Part" in the title used as the running header in the text pages to become lowercase. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Consider adding a MNWE?

Comment: `Non Italic \textit{Italicized Part} Non Italic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piggybacking on [WillAdams' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121943/80), you'll also need to use a typeface that provides italic small caps.  Linux Libertine and Minion Pro are a couple such typefaces:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\title{Non Italic \protect\textit{Italicized} Part Non Italic}
\author[The Tufte-LaTeX Developers]{The Tufte-LaTeX\ Developers}
\publisher{Publisher of This Book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Use Linux Libertine as the main text font
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
\renewcommand\allcapsspacing[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=15}#1}}
\renewcommand\smallcapsspacing[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10}#1}}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

% Test that we have italic small caps
\itshape italic \scshape small caps \normalfont

Test\clearpage
pages
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the running heads are set as small caps.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\title{Non Italic \protect\textit{Italicized} Part Non Italic}
\author[The Tufte-LaTeX Developers]{The Tufte-LaTeX\ Developers}
\publisher{Publisher of This Book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Test\clearpage
pages
\end{document}
```

You'll need to re-define the running head command so that it marks that one is w/in such an environment, then define an emphasis command which checks to see if it's w/in a running head and when it is, applies \textsc --- alternately, Memoir includes a tufte-inspired appearance, it may be better behaved --- it's certainly more thoroughly documented.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the heads up, WillAdams.